# Azure Worker Role VM specifications

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

How can we learn the specifications of the Virtual Machine on which we are running the worker role? I call C++ functions and some functions use SIMD instructions and threads. My question is: Is there an instructional limit on the running code? Obviously, visual studio creates compatible code when the project is targeted for azure platform. But what happens if I call a dll function? Is it always safe if the dll is compiled for an x64 PC?

Comment: Have looked at the [FAQ](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/faq/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Azure runs entirely on 64 bit, which they don't mention as a feature as such, it's just mentioned throughout the documentation.  It tends to come up when [people want to run 32 bit dlls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443399/32-bit-legacy-com-dlls-on-windows-azure).  There is a lesson in the training kit for [building your own c++ dlls to run on Windows Azure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsazure/WAZPlatformTrainingCourse_WindowsAzureNativeCode).  The short version is that if you're only ever running your .dll on 64 bit machines, compiling for x64 is fine.