# 32 bit WCF on Azure - enable32BitAppOnWin64 not working

Tags: wcf, iis, azure

I am trying to get a 32 bit WCF library to run on Azure. I've read several posts, like this: [32-bit legacy COM DLLs on Windows Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443399/32-bit-legacy-com-dlls-on-windows-azure), saying that they successfully force IIS to load a 32 bit application.

I added the startup batch file, which also registers a COM, and I see that it is run successfully. The COM is registered and the setting is set to true in IIS manager.

Yet the role keeps recycling and in the Event Viewer I see:

`WaIISHost
Role entrypoint could not be created: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or   assembly 'file:///E:\approot\bin\wcfAzureWrapperStoryMapping.dll' or one of its dependencies.  An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
File name: 'file:///E:\approot\bin\wcfAzureWrapperStoryMapping.dll'`

I tried changing the OS from Windows 2008 to Windows 2012, no effect. What is going on?

And the funny part, the `base` folder contains two folders, x64 and x86. So it's like there is a provision for 32 bit. How do I force these guys to cooperate? I was thinking to rename the folders from the batch file but it's probably not going to work...

**UPDATE**: funny enough, Task Manager shows IISConfigurator as 32 bit! What's going on, I wonder?

Comment: Rule of thumb is that you should follow your service provider's supportability, not something discovered by someone on the Internet. Microsoft states clearly that it is a pure 64 bit system, and you should follow that. Note that WOW64 might present on Windows Server 2008 R2, but it is not present on Windows Server 2012 and above in default installation any more.

Comment: @LexLi, the advice to tweak the setting was on the MSDN blogs website as well as in several other places. But in other words, you have no idea, is this correct?

Comment: Sorry, how is that "off-topic"? It's very close to what others are asking, just because you don't know the answer and I flagged your comment, it doesn't mean you have to right to close the question. The whole "thought police" thing here has gotten ridiculous.